# Text field insertion is wrong with Phonegap although cursor display is correct before insertion

Tags: text, cordova, cursor, position, field

I am having a problem with phonegap text field.  I formatted the digits in the text field with punctuation so the length of the digits increases.  The newly entered digit will not be at the end of the formatted string so the insertion position is wrong although the cursor always shows at the end of the text field.  This same code works fine in phonegap phone simulator but not on a phone with Android 2.3.

Example:

Starting with a blank field, I enter 123456.  The cursor always shows at the end of the digits.  I used entry.value = number to update the text after I inserted punctuation into the digits.

```
    1         correct
    12        correct
    1.23      correct
    12.43     wrong, expecting 12.34
    1:24.53   wrong again, expecting 1:23.45
    12:46.53  wrong, expecting 12:34.56
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried the same code on a newer phone (with newer Android) and the problem didn't exist.  It must have been a bug on Android 2.3 and had been fixed.